# Linux - rendering performance after switching from nvidia to nouveau drivers

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia, opengl, nouveau

I use UBuntu 14.04 LTS. I have purged all nvidia proprietary drivers and currently my system use Nouveau driver. Here is an output from `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` :

when using nvidia propietary drivers

```
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 970/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3.0 NVIDIA 346.59
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 346.59
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

when using nouveau driver

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
```

When I run a [gpu benchmark](http://www.geeks3d.com/gputest/) triangle test I get following results:

- nvidia driver: 304455 points, 5073fps
- nouveau driver: 8466 points, 142 fps

There is a massive drop in performance. Can I change something in nouveau settings to get better results ?

**Edit1**

`glxinfo |egrep  -w 'rendering|renderer'` :

- direct rendering: Yes
- OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 256 bits)

I don't use the system in Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if 3d is enabled?

```
glxinfo |egrep  -w 'rendering|renderer'
```

If you read something about "raster" or "no",then is not enabled.
Even if enabled the opensource driver are good,but there is a lot of work to do
to reach at least for old cards the same performance of the nvidia proprietary driver.

Is not clear this

"OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc."
Using this in a vm?

Comment: Please see Edit1

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to look into your `/var/log/Xorg.*.log` file (where `*` means the first number in your `$DISPLAY` environment variable) to find out why 3D acceleration hasn't been enabled. `Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe` is a software renderer, so this indicates that nouveau is not really in use. You can also try the following command to check for warnings about misconfiguration of libGL:

```
LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo > /dev/null
```

This will redirect all the normal output of `glxinfo` to `/dev/null` (the "hole" device) while retaining all the warnings on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered same issue, but under different circumstances. Only available renderer was llvm.

After lot of googling I realised, because of different bug, I put nomodeset into grub (`/etc/default/grub`) in the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`

In my setup the machine works without this parameter just fine.

Check, if there is parameter `nomodeset` in grub and remove it.
Try if it helps.